# Install repository and sync project makes android studio freeze

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

I tried to get the latest version of the google play services for the maps api, using `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.2.0'` in the gradle file and also put the google maven url in the project gradle.

My problem is that when i try to sync my gradle files, i get an error and android studio proposes to *install repository and sync project*, but when i click on it nothing happens and android studio freezes for a few seconds.
The same happens if i add the whole google play services with `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.2.0'`

I tried the *invalidate cache/restart* technique, i uninstalled/installed the google play service in the sdk manager and i don't know what to do to resolve this problem.

The build.gradle is like this (it works with the 11.0.4 version) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def dbflow_version = "4.0.5"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "not telling"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    annotationProcessor "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-processor:${dbflow_version}"
    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow-core:${dbflow_version}"
    compile "com.github.Raizlabs.DBFlow:dbflow:${dbflow_version}"

    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.0.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
}
```

Do you have a way to fix this ?

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: Post build.gradle

Comment: i just put it in the initial question

Comment: We have to get the log of android studio to debug your problem. On linux, start android studio using command line, you can get log from the console. On MacOSX, you can use **console.app** find the log.